# Does SPARC v9 have a double word compare and swap instruction?

Tags: c, lock-free, sparc

So; on a 64 bit SPARC CPU which is v9 compliant, there exists I know a **cas** instruction.  This operates on single word length values.

I've also seen on the web reference to a **casx** instruction - but I can't find out anything much more about it.

I'm wondering - is this a double word compare and swap?

And if not, the general question is; IS there a double word compare and swap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparc64 - alone amongst modern CPUs - implements neither double wide CAS nor LL/SC.  As such, implementing lock-free code is problematic.  There a solutions, but they are solutions to a problem (ABA) which does not exist on other platforms because of their support for CAS or LL/SC.  Furthermore, a range of lock-free algorithms cannot be implemented on Sparce because of this limitation.

Comment: Actually, once you implement SMR, you're fine on SPARC.

Answer (score 1):

CASXA.  See [The SPARC Architecture Manual](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/sparcv9.pdf).

Comment: CASA swaps 32 bit values.  CASXA swaps 64 bit values.  Sparc v9 as I understand it is a 64 bit CPU.  I'm looking for a double-word CAS, e.g. 128 bits on a 64 bit CPU.  I looks then like this does not exist on Sparc.

Comment: Ah... the old ambiguity of "word" in an architecture which expand.

Comment: Yes - I realised when I read the manual, Sparc thinks of word as 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that `casx` does exist, however it's a synthetic instruction (i.e. a simplified mnemonic) for `casxa`. See *Table 43* in the aforementioned SPARC Architecture Manual:

```
Synthetic:   casx [regrs1], regrs2, regrd 
Instruction: casxa [regrs1]#ASI_P, regrs2, regrd 
Description: compare and swap extended
```

Comment: Ahh - I *wondered* what Sun meant when they said synthetic instruction.